# Do Phoenixes retain their memories when they rise from the ashes?

Tags: harry-potter, phoenix

According to [Harry Potter wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fawkes)

> Dumbledore cared for his [Phoenix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_%28mythology%29) Fawkes after each of his
>   rebirths, and in return he (Fawkes) was very faithful to the elderly
>   wizard.

When told the bird had burst into flames Albus said to Harry:

> "About time, too. He's been looking dreadful for days; I've been
>   telling him to get a move on."

The legend says they die and are born anew. Do Phoenixes retain their memories when they rise from the ashes?

Comment: Of course it retains its memories, it knew who Dumbledore was. I wonder how long a Phoenix's memory lasts and how intelligent they are. A crow is said to have a memory of up to 5 years.

Comment: @GorchestopherH A hand raised bird will always bond with its human.

Comment: Exactly. If the phoenix retains its bond between incarnations, it's a strong indication that it's memories are retained.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ‘It’s a shame you had to see him on a Burning Day,’ said Dumbledore, seating himself behind his desk. ‘He’s really very handsome most of the time: wonderful red and gold plumage.
>   Fascinating creatures, phoenixes. They can carry immensely heavy loads, their tears have healing powers and they make highly *faithful* pets.’
>   *Chamber of Secrets* - page 155 - Bloomsbury - chapter 12, *The Polyjuice Potion*

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/faithful?s=t) offers the following as definitions for faithful: steady in allegiance or affection; loyal; **constant**: *faithful friends*.

As **Gorchestopher H** mentioned, Fawkes apparently knew who Dumbledore was each time he burned and regenerated. In the above passage I quoted from *Chamber of Secrets*, J.K. Rowling put the emphasis on "faithful", not me. In order for Fawkes to exhibit characteristics like steadiness in allegiance or affection, loyalty, and constancy, I think Fawkes would have to retain his memory with each regeneration.

Comment: What's to say, though, that it doesn't have some sort of "first thing I see is Mother" hard-wiring? While I agree with you, why couldn't it be that each molting it just re-accepts Dumbledore as its parent? Admittedly, one would wonder why Dumbledore would be so calm having another person in the room, then...

Comment: Slytherincess @rsegal , if you're right about the "[first thing I see is Mother](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Are_You_My_Mother%3F)", that might explain why Fawkes came to the Chamber of Secrets to save Harry. Maybe Dumbledore planned the whole thing in advance, and what he really meant was "*It is all part of my diabolical plan that you see him on a Burning Day, muhuhahaha*".

Comment: @NominSim: ah, nice theory.

Comment: He _is_ known to be a chess-master bar none. Now, if you'll excuse me, I need to go find my tinfoil hat!

Comment: @NominSim - You guys are talking about imprinting, IIRC. I think it would depend on how often Fawkes has a burning cycle. When Harry saw Fawkes burn, it was the third week of December; the events in the Chamber of Secrets occurred in the summer term. In Potterverse that would suggest 5-6 months from Fawkes's last burn to the events in the chamber. Would Fawkes have imprinted on Harry for that long? :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Your answer says "constant: faithful friends", so *if* his burning hadn't occurred again, perhaps he had remained imprinted. Also Harry's *loyal* wand has one of his tail feather's, so *part of Fawkes* is still loyal after all those years. (Being intentionally over-the-top.) #conspiracy

Comment: @NominSim - Props for conspiracy! Like **rsegal**, I love a good reason to break out my tin hat. :)

Comment: @NominSim -- I just happened across this quote from JKR regarding Fawkes and thought you might be interested in it: "*Something had to leave the school for good when Dumbledore died, and I decided that would be Fawkes. Dumbledore was a very great and irreplacable man, and the loss of Fawkes (and the fact that he was ‘non-transferable’!) expresses this symbolically*." I think by "non-transferable" JKR means that Dumbledore is the only person who held ownership of Fawkes. Just an FYI! :)

Comment: @Slytherincess: perhaps add that quote to your answer.